# Why is my console logging: `TimeoutOverflowWarning: 4294967296000 does not fit into a 32-bit signed integer`

Tags: node.js, through2

I am following the course [stream-adventure](https://github.com/workshopper/stream-adventure). One of the assignments is to make an http server which converts all the requests to uppercase and return it in the response.

Now I managed to get it working and the assignment passes. However, the console gives me a TimeoutOverflowWarning.

```
(node:15710) TimeoutOverflowWarning: 4294967296000 does not fit into a 32-bit signed integer.
Timer duration was truncated to 2147483647.
(node:15710) TimeoutOverflowWarning: 4294967296000 does not fit into a 32-bit signed integer.
Timer duration was truncated to 2147483647.
```

I'm wondering if it's a memory leak or something caused by my code, or if it is something else. Because in the error message 32-bit is mentioned, I wonder if it's related to that I'm using a Macbook Pro from 2016 which runs in 64 bit. (node v10.17.0)

The code:

```
'use-strict'
const through = require('through2')
const http = require('http')
const port = process.argv[2]

const uppercaser = through(function (buffer, _, next) {
  this.push(buffer.toString().toUpperCase())
  next()
});

const server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    res.writeHead(200,  { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' })
    req.pipe(uppercaser).pipe(res)
  } else {
    res.writeHead(404)
    res.end()
  }
});

server.listen(port)
```

Google searches give various causes of this problem ([example 1](https://github.com/substack/hyperquest/pull/63), [example 2](https://github.com/dpskvn/express-sse/commit/bd225946bf3c3029100a92828a9d92a13defb69f)) and it seems that most of the solutions are fixed in library used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the problem related to `setTimeout` \ `setInterval` functions. They have a limit of 32-bit as you can see. So that the `node` is warning you about it:

```sh
> setTimeout(console.log, +Infinity)

> (node:19903) TimeoutOverflowWarning: Infinity does not fit into a 32-bit signed integer.
Timeout duration was set to 1.
```

Since your code does not have any of those, it seems like the problem with some code in library.

I'd recommend to run `node` with `--trace-warnings` [flag](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_trace_warnings) to find the source of warning:

> **--trace-warnings**
>
> Print stack traces for process warnings (including deprecations).

Answer (score 8):

When I find this type of error is when I use a `setInterval` function.

This is because the upper limit of the timeout is 2147483647 which is the max limit of 32-bit int.

If you want you can make your own `setInterval` wrapper

```js
function setDaysTimeout(callback,days) {
    // 86400 seconds in a day
    let msInDay = 86400*1000; 

    let dayCount = 0;
    let timer = setInterval(function() {
        dayCount++;  // a day has passed

        if (dayCount === days) {
           clearInterval(timer);
           callback.apply(this, []);
        }
    }, msInDay);
}
```

And use it like this:

```js
setDaysTimeout(function() {
     console.log('Four days gone');
}, 4); // fire after 4 days
```

Answer (score 0):

The upper limit of the timeout is 2147483647, which is the max limit of 32-bit int. In order to avoid this you can wait for the max time and then wait for any  remaining time.

```
const timeout = async (callback, time, callbackArguments) => {
  if (!callback || typeof callback !== 'function') throw new Error('Invalid Callback')
  let args = ((callbackArguments && typeof callbackArguments === 'object' && 
    callbackArguments.length > 0) ? callbackArguments : [])
  let max = 2147483647
  if (time > max) {
    let t = Math.floor(time / max)
    let r = time%max
    for (let i = 0; i < t; i++) await (() => new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => res(), max)))();
    if (r) {
        return setTimeout(() => callback(...args), r)
    } else {
        return callback(...args)
    }
  } else {
    return setTimeout(() => callback(...args), time)
  }
}
```

Use like so

```
let a = 2
let b = 5
let c = (a, b) => console.log(!a && !b ? 0 : !a && b ? b : a && !b ? a : a + b)
let now = new Date().getTime()
let later = now + 2147483647*5
timeout(c, later-now, [a,b])
```

Comment: Could you extend your answer with an explanation of why code from the question didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple extension over original setTimeout to accept any timeout values.

```
const xSetTimeout = (() => {
    const MAX_INT = 2 ** 31 - 1;

    return function _xSetTimeout(cb, timeout) {
        if (timeout <= MAX_INT)
            return setTimeout(cb, timeout);
        return setTimeout(
            () => _xSetTimeout(cb, timeout - MAX_INT),
            MAX_INT);
    }
})();
```